# Add additional labels in SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a chart in SSRS with horizontal and vertical axis. The chart is as shown in the figure below. I need to add some calculated labels (marked with black) on top of the chart (example is from Excel). How can this be done in SSRS charts?

Labels and smart labels won't work in this case because of the series. It will show values for each group (ex: red, blue, yellow). I just want it once in the totals.

[image: SSRS chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I found that the best way is to create a new chart (ex: Line Chart)
   with value 0.
2. Then select Secondary Axis for the Horizontal Axis.
3. Set the Data Point --> Axis Label to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

1. Create a second dataset that fetches the values you want for the Data Labels
2. Select the Series in the Chart and in the Properties pane going to Labels, then set UseValueAsLabel = False
3. Set the "Label" property to be a LookUp() that fetched the appropriate value from my second dataset
4. Use the "Visible" property to hide the labels for the other series so that        they no longer show.

You can then change the label position to force them at the top of the columns